# Exception handling in URL builder method

Tags: java, beginner, url, rest

I have a method which is part of a request-handling class. It creates a URL, depending on the resource send request.

This is a part of the REST service:

```
private static URL addQueryToUrl(String qry) {
    try {
        if ("playerProfile".equals(requestingService)) {
            return new URL(PLAYER_URL + qry);
        } else if ("search".equals(requestingService)) {
            return new URL(SEARCH_URL   + qry);
        } else {
            throw new Exception();
        }
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        System.out.println("wrong url format");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("no such a requestingService");
    }
    return null;
}
```

I have 2 questions:

1. What exception should I throw if `requestingService` is not recognized? For now, my method is throwing `Exception`. Or should I handle such an exception on a higher level, when `requestingService` has an assigned value?
2. If no URL is built, what value should I return? NULL? I'm now reading *Clean Code* by Robert C. Martin and he is stating that returning null is bad practise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we are speaking in terms of *Clean Code*, the entire method should be revised.

Here are the main points that I can criticize:

1. `if ... else if ...` branches are used to match Strings: this approach is too verbose and not very flexible.
2. `URL` is instantiated in two different places, with same semantics.
3. The `Exception` thrown in `else` block is immediately caught and thus is useless.
4. The catch blocks hide exception details and trace, which is annoying for debugging.
5. Returning `null` is ugly. A better choice would be either to return an `Optional` or throw the exception outside the method.

This method does two distinct things:

1) Determine which URL to use depending on the `requestingService` value.

2) Instantiate a `URL` object with `query` suffix.

Each of these things should be wrapped in a dedicated method.

So let's first create the `getServiceUrl` method:

```
private static String getServiceUrl() {
  switch (requestingService) {
    case "playerProfile": return PLAYER_URL;
    case "search": return SEARCH_URL;
    default: throw new IllegalStateException("Unexpected requestingService value=" + requestingService);
  }
}
```

Here I suppose that `requestingService` member of this class can take only a predefined set of values (and even should be transformed into an `enum`!) and any value that is not in this set denotes an internal problem that puts the application into an invalid state.

BTW, since the original method is `static`, I suppose that `requestingService` is also a static member and therefore should be renamed according to style conventions. And I also suspect that there is some misuse of statics, but can't say more about it without having the entire code.

Second, we rewrite the original method:

```
private static URL addQueryToUrl(String qry) {
  try {
    return new URL(getServiceUrl() + qry);
  } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    throw new IllegalStateException(e);
  }
}
```

Since `PLAYER_URL` and `SEARCH_URL` are pre-validated constants, I suppose that they cannot represent a cause for a `MalformedURLException`. But from the original code, it is not clear whether `qry` is validated as part of URL pattern or not. If so, an `IllegalStateException` would be appropriate here. Otherwise the catch block should log the exception message and return an `Optional.empty()` instead (also change the return type to `Optional<URL>` and the return statement respectively).

I'd also suggest to rename this method to `buildUrlWithQuery`.

Answer (score 0):

> What exception should I throw if requestingService is not recognized?
>   For now, my method is throwing Exception. Or should I handle such an
>   exception on a higher level, when requestingService has an assigned
>   value?

I would suggest throwing an exception when requestingService is not set. I'd probably make a new Exception class to handle it, or just have the set method return false if it fails to set the value. Given you haven't shown where/how it is set, I can't offer more assistance than that.

> If no URL is built, what value should I return? NULL? I'm now reading
>   Clean Code by Robert C. Martin and he is stating that returning null
>   is bad practise.

Personally, I think returning null is fine. If you want to avoid returning null, you could throw an exception, make the method declare that it throws the exception, and let the calling code handle it. I'd do the same with the exception handling you currently have... as a rule, services don't (shouldn't?) know enough context about what they are doing to properly handle exceptions.

Comment: I assume you meant "when `requestingService` is **not** set"? Since that is a String I think you may be overcautios assuming that setting it could fail in any non-catastrophic way. I unfortunately have to disagree about returning `null`. It's IMO a codesmell to even have the possibility of returning null in such an integral part of an application

Comment: Yes, I meant **not** set. Thanks. I have edited to fix. It may well be a String, but I think the exception should be thrown when it is set rather than when it is to be used... makes it easier to track the problem down.